# Equivalent of find_each for foo_ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Given this model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
end
```

Then we can do this::

```
@user = User.find(123)
@user.things.find_each{ |t| print t.name }
@user.thing_ids.each{ |id| print id }
```

There are a large number of `@user.things` and I want to iterate through only their ids in batches, like with `find_each`. Is there a handy way to do this?

The goal is to:

- not load the entire `thing_ids` array into memory at once
- still only load arrays of `thing_ids`, and not instantiate a `Thing` for each id

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails 5 introduced [`in_batches`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-in_batches) method, which yields a relation and uses `pluck(primary_key)` internally. And we can make use of the [`where_values_hash`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0.0.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-where_values_hash) method of the relation in order to retrieve already-plucked ids:

```rb
@user.things.in_batches { |batch_rel| p batch_rel.where_values_hash['id'] }
```

Note that `in_batches` has `order` and `limit` restrictions similar to `find_each`.

This approach is a bit hacky since it depends on the internal implementation of `in_batches` and will fail if `in_batches` stops plucking ids in the future. A non-hacky method would be `batch_rel.pluck(:id)`, but this runs the same pluck query twice.

Comment: does this only pluck id? What's the SQL call that is made for each batch?

Comment: @JohnBachir it just gets the ids from the current batch relation's where statement. The SQL is of the form `SELECT  "things"."id" FROM "things" WHERE "things"."user_id" = USER_ID AND ("things"."id" > LAST_THING_ID_FROM_PREV_BATCH) ORDER BY "things"."id" ASC LIMIT BATCH_SIZE`. You can see the source code just under the API docs as well.

Comment: Okay then I'm changing this to be The Answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below, the each slice will take 4 elements at a time and them you can loop around the 4

```
@user.thing_ids.each_slice(4) do |batch|
  batch.each do |id|
   puts id
   end
end
```

Comment: Right but `thing_ids` will load all of them into memory, which I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE Final EDIT:**

I have updated my answer after reviewing your updated question (not sure why you would downvote after I backed up my answer with source code to prove it...but I don't hold grudges :)

Here is my solution, tested and working, so you can accept this as the answer if it pleases you.

Below, I have extended ActiveRecord::Relation, overriding the find_in_batches method to accept one additional option, :relation. When set to true, it will return the activerecord relation to your block, so you can then use your desired method 'pluck' to get only the ids of the target query.

```
#put this file in your lib directory:
#active_record_extension.rb
module ARAExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def find_in_batches(options = {})
    options.assert_valid_keys(:start, :batch_size, :relation)

    relation = self
    start = options[:start]
    batch_size = options[:batch_size] || 1000

    unless block_given?
      return to_enum(:find_in_batches, options) do
        total = start ? where(table[primary_key].gteq(start)).size : size
        (total - 1).div(batch_size) + 1
      end
    end

    if logger && (arel.orders.present? || arel.taken.present?)
      logger.warn("Scoped order and limit are ignored, it's forced to be batch order and batch size")
    end

    relation = relation.reorder(batch_order).limit(batch_size)
    records = start ? relation.where(table[primary_key].gteq(start)) : relation

    records = records.to_a unless options[:relation]

    while records.any?
      records_size = records.size
      primary_key_offset = records.last.id
      raise "Primary key not included in the custom select clause" unless primary_key_offset

      yield records

      break if records_size < batch_size

      records = relation.where(table[primary_key].gt(primary_key_offset))
      records = records.to_a unless options[:relation]
    end
  end

end

ActiveRecord::Relation.send(:include, ARAExtension)
```

here is the initializer

```
#put this file in config/initializers directory:
#extensions.rb
require "active_record_extension"
```

Originally, this method forced a conversion of the relation to an array of activrecord objects and returned it to you. Now, I optionally allow you to return the query before the conversion to the array happens. Here is an example of how to use it:

```
@user.things.find_in_batches(:batch_size=>10, :relation=>true).each do |batch_query|
  # do any kind of further querying/filtering/mapping that you want

  # show that this is actually an activerecord relation, not an array of AR objects
  puts batch_query.to_sql
  # add more conditions to this query, this is just an example
  batch_query = batch_query.where(:color=>"blue")
  # pluck just the ids
  puts batch_query.pluck(:id)
end
```

Ultimately, if you don't like any of the answers given on an SO post, you can roll-your-own solution. Consider only downvoting when an answer is either way off topic or not helpful in any way. We are all just trying to help. Downvoting an answer that has source code to prove it will only deter others from trying to help you.

**Previous EDIT**

In response to your comment (because my comment would not fit):

1. calling
   [thing_ids](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8e3b1a632c15e8c7f708ab222a81faaad8e3410e/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb#LC63)
   internally uses
   [pluck](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/70ac072976c8cc6f013f0df3777e54ccae3f4f8c/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb#LC153)
2. pluck internally uses
   [select_all](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/da8de9114b41618322dde17c35b891ade46751fe/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L30)
3. ...which instantiates an activerecord [Result](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Result)

Previous 2nd EDIT:

This line of code within pluck returns an activerecord [Result](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Result):

```
 ....
 result = klass.connection.select_all(relation.arel, nil, bound_attributes)
 ...
```

I just stepped through the source code for you. Using [select_all](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/da8de9114b41618322dde17c35b891ade46751fe/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb#L30) will save you some memory, but in the end, an activerecord [Result](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Result) was still created and mapped over even when you are using the pluck method.

Comment: Thanks for the big answer, but 1) In this case I actually do want all of the `thing_ids` 2) find_in_batches will create a `Thing` object in memory, which I don't want to do.

Comment: the code you point to in line 4 is accessing a database connection, it is not instantiating a `Thing` for each id. `pluck` in general will not instantiate an activerecord object for each row. The purpose of `pluck` is to get a bare array of values.

Comment: I'm not arguing that a Thing is creating for each id, I'm telling you that internally pluck is calling klass.connection.select_all which is indeeded creating an activerecord Result, and then mapping over it. Step through the source code.

Comment: `select_all` creates a single `ActiveRecord::Result` to hold **all the rows** returned, not an individual object per row. It's the instantiation of a `Thing` object per row that the OP doesn't want.

Comment: Yes, I understand that he does not want the Thing objects instantiated after he updated his post. But what I was originally trying to point out is that the method pluck internally is creating an ActiveRecord::Result, which, from what it looks like, is just a wrapper around a hash and therefore, does not **instantiate any Thing objects**, conserving memory. Regardless, I programmed a solution for him that accomplishes his updated goals.

Comment: @Mike.MKrallaProductions I downvoted you for your abusive language, which you have now toned down in your edit, so I removed my downvote. your new answer is epic! but i think i wouldn't want to have such a large complete method override in my app. is it possible to do it with `alias_method_chain` or just making a new special method?

Answer (score 0):

It is, unfortunately, not a one-liner or helper that will allow you to do this, so instead:

```
limit = 1000
offset = 0
loop do
  batch = @user.things.limit(limit).offset(offset).pluck(:id)
  batch.each { |id| puts id }
  break if batch.count < limit
  offset += limit
end
```

Comment: This is the best answer for Rails < 5

Answer (score -1):

I would use something like this:

```
User.things.find_each(batch_size: 1000).map(&:id)
```

This will give you an array of the ids.

Comment: But it will also create a `Thing` object in memory for each user, which I don't want to do.